# Drone in an elevator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, velocity

I just watched this video, [What Happens If You Fly a Drone In An Elevator? Real Experiment!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUGwdcgi2L8)

To my surprise, the answer was not what I expected.  I thought the drone would stay stationary.  My thought was that the elevator is a closed system and the air is part of that system.  The drone is pushing against the air in the elevator, which is moving with the elevator.  So the drone should stay in place, assuming there is no change in acceleration.

Clearly, the video debunks my thought.  The presenter says it is because the drone is not a part of that closed system - at least thats how I interpreted it.

Is the presenter right?  If so, can someone give a clearer explanation?  Or maybe the presenter and I are both wrong and there is a different explanation?

Comment: Remember gravity, not only air pressure. For the drone to fly it is working against gravity, What happens if you let fall a pencil from your hand in the elevator?

Comment: Technically drone stays in place, but relative to the sea level of Earth. To stay in place relative to the moving elevator, you have to move together with elevator, which drone apparently does not do, hence it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible for a human to fly a quad copter. The 'copter is too unstable. Only a computer, using input from multiple inertial sensors, can react quickly enough to tiny disurbances in the airflow, and keep the vehicle flying or hovering as commanded by the operator.

That little toy's guidance computer uses *only* its inertial sensors. When the joysticks are in the neutral position, it works to keep the drone from accelerating in any direction. So, when the elevator, including the air inside the elevator, accelerates upward or downward, the drone's guidance system feels the unexpected acceleration as a "disturbance" for which it must correct. The elevator accelerates, but the drone does not, and the ceiling or the floor of the elevator quickly crashes into it.

I own a slightly more sophisticated toy 'copter that also has a downward facing optical sensor, and it uses that to maintain a constant height above a surface. If mine is hovering above my outstretched hand, and I raise or lower my hand, the drone moves up or down with my hand.

Comment: Interesting.  I didnt think about the technology on the drone.  So lets assume a drone *could* be perfectly stable without sensors and a computer, taking away those variables.  What would happen?

Comment: @Keltari, You could do that experiment with a toy helium balloon that was ballasted to be neutrally buoyant. It should just move with the air. And, if there's no fan going inside the elevator, and the doors are closed, then I would expect the air to move with the elevator car.